# Implementation of Autoencoder

Tags: java, machine-learning, backpropagation, autoencoder

I'm trying to implement an **Auto-encoder** by my own in Java. From the theory, I understood that auto-encoder is basically a symmetric network.

So, if I chose to have 5 layers in total, do I have to use 9 layers in training (**back propagation**) phase or 5 layers enough?

I've been reading theory but they are too abstract and full of math formulas, I could not get any implementation details via google.

What's the usual way of doing this?

[image]

An **Auto-encoder**, in training phase, using back propagation, tries to get the output similar to the input with a goal to minimize the error. It is shown above. The number of layers in the above image are 7 while the actual layers are 4 after the training. So, while training can I implement the **back-propagation** with just 4? If so, how can I do this?

Comment: There's an implementation of autoencoders and restricted Boltzmann machines on deeplearning4j.org. The intro is here: deeplearning4j.org/restrictedboltzmannmachine.html

Answer (score 3):

Simple backpropagation **won't work** with so many layers. Due to so called **vanishing gradient** pehenomen, networks having more than two hidden layers won't learn anything reasonable. In fact, best results are obtained with **one** hidden layer. So in case of autoencoder you should have INPUT layer, HIDDEN layer and OUTPUT layer. No need for more, the Universal Approximation Theorem clearly shows, that this is enough for any problem.

From the OOP point of view it depends whether you plan to reuse this code with different types of neurons, and by type of neuron I mean something deeper than just different activation function - different behaviour (stochastic neurons?); different topologies (not fully connected networks). If not - modeling each neuron as a separate object is completely redundant.

Comment: I know this....I'm planning to use RBMs for pretraining...Meanwhile, I'm doing this to get an idea of implementation..and I'm not sure if I have to use double the number of layers in training or just the right number of layers in (double because I have to get the input from input)

Comment: It does not really matter whether you use RBM or not - RBMs are also (efficiently) trainable only with 1 hidden layer. Training of deep autoencoder is **not** what you have painted.

Comment: Please clarify me about the implementation detail I asked..... but this paper of Geoffry Hinton suggests to use multiple layers... http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.220.3054&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: Can you please tell me whether I should use in total seven layers when we actually need 4 layers after training? Refer to the last para of my question please....

Comment: Your question lacks many aspects. What is the purpose of the network. How is it exactly trained. In general it seems very bizzare idea to "unfold" autoencoder despite its application.

Comment: My application learns binary code for images, I'm using autoencoder for it....My problem is its implementation....whether to initialize symmetric network or to only initialize half of the network and somehow pass the output backwards to compare with the inputs..